# Is it possible to execute pentaho step in sequence?

Tags: pentaho, data-import, data-integration

I have a pentaho transformation which is consist of, for example, 10 steps. I want to start this job for N input parameters but not in parallel, each job evaluation should start after previous transformation are fully completed(process done in transaction and commited or rollbacked). Is it possible with Pentaho?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add 'Block this step until steps finish' from Flow to your transformation. Or you can mix 'Wait for SQL' component from Utility with loop on your job.

Regards
Mateusz

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you must do it using jobs instead of transformations. Jobs only run on sequence while transformations run on parallel. (Truly, a transformation has a initialize phase whose run is in parallel and then the flow runs sequentially).

If you can't use jobs, you always can do what Matusz said.